# scrollbar on table content, android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, scroll, html-table

I need to have a table content with scrollbar in an android app using html, javascript and css.

I already tried to search a lot of examples and plugins but with no success, many of them are telling me to do like this one below. I have to put over-flow:auto, some size to the height and display:block, but I tried that and all the content was aligned only to the first column and didn't work.

```html
<table>
     <thead>
          <tr>
                 <th>title 01</th>
                 <th>title 02</th>
                 <th>title 03</th>
                 <th>title 04</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
     <div>
           <tbody>
                  <tr>
                        <td> content row col 01</td>
                        <td> content row col 02</td>
                        <td> content row col 03</td>
                        <td> content row col 04</td>
                  </tr>
           </tbody>
     </div>
</table>
```

Please, I need some solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I used this jquery plugin [jquery.jtablescroll.js](https://github.com/farinspace/jquery.tableScroll).

Import js on your page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.tablescroll.js"></script>
```

and into html page put the table with content like the example below:

```
<table id="tableId"> 
    <thead>
        <th>Column Header 01</th>
        <th>Column Header 02</th>
        <th>Column Header 03</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
        <td>Column Content</td>
        <td>Column Content</td>
        <td>Column Content</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and in javascript of your html you'll need to activate jtablescroll to your table, do like this one below, setting the id of your table and height of it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
       $('#tableId').tableScroll({height:600});
});
```

Naturally, you don't wanna create a table with static content, so remember to activate the plugin to your table in javascript just after the content had been gotten from server and rows of the table had been added dinamically to the tbody for example like this:

jQuery('#tableId tbody').append(contentList);

I hope this can help somebody that had this problem.